# High performance computing pthread parameters - c++

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, pthreads, posix

I'm working on a project where I need to use multiple threads using pthread (C++).
I have a question:

What is the best pthread parameter configuration setting for when I want to do some high performance computing in that thread without too much other threads interrupting it?

Currently I'm using something like this:

```
pthread_t thread;

struct sched_param param;
int sched = SCHED_FIFO;
memset(&param, 0, sizeof(sched_param));

// Now I set priority to max value (sched_get_priority_max() returns that value)
param.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max();

// Create my thread
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, (void *) &hard_number_crunching, (void *) &structure_passed_to_thread);

// finally I set parameters to thread
pthread_setschedparam(&thread, sched, &param);
```

I was switching "int sched" between SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR, but it didn't help me much.
Is it possible to force this thread to run longer on the CPU than it is at the moment?

Comment: When you say "it didn't help me much" what do you mean? How are you measuring this?  Are you concerned with latency (the responsiveness of your thread) or throughput (how much work your system does per unit time)?

Comment: I'd tag it as C better

Comment: High performance with multithreading is all about good data organization and efficient inter-thread comms.  Beside that, fiddling with scheduling algorithms, priorites etc. is of next-to-no importance.

Comment: 'Is it possible to force this thread to run longer on the CPU than it is at the moment?'  - why would it not run on a CPU at 100%?  What else is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating one thread per core, you probably want to set the thread's affinity to prevent it from roaming between cores. This usually improves the performance by ensuring that each thread remains close to its cached data. See:

```
int sched_setaffinity(pid_t pid,size_t cpusetsize,cpu_set_t *mask);
```

Note: you should not set the affinity if you are creating more threads than cores! This could cause all kind of crazy things to happen, deadlocks to mention one.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try this one. Will tell you how it went tomorrow.

Comment: @amdn I get some continuous data input that never stops, and I want to spend as much time as possible analyzing that input data. I am not too much concerned about responsiveness atm.

Comment: @Martin James there are other processes interrupting and using the CPU. I would like to hog CPU all to myself as much as possible when my process is running.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your thread is going to take X cycles.  It doesn't matter what the priority is, or what else the system is doing, it's still going to take X cycles.  If the system is not busy doing other things, your thread will run nearly continuously until it finishes.  If the system is busy, your thread will be stopped, perhaps even frequently, to let other things run.  Eventually your thread will still get its X cycles.  Note that for your purposes here, there are two types of priorities... thread priorities (the priority of your one thread versus the priority of your other threads), and process priorities (the priority of your process/program versus the priority of other processes/programs/operating-system).  You're setting the thread priority.  Do you have other threads of equal or higher priority competing with this one?  Are there system processes of higher priority competing with yours?  If the answer is no, you'll pretty much get the CPU to yourself.  Also note, if you have multiple processors and/or cores, your thread may not run well on more than one, so your overall system processing may not be 100% if you haven't divided up your tasks well.

Comment: Thank you very much, you made the whole concept much clearer to me. So what if there are 2 processes running on the OS, for example process1 and process2. Each of those processes has 3 threads. If every thread in process1 has priority set to some default value (normal), and we set 1 thread in process2 to highest priority. So now we have 3 normal priority threads in process1, 2 normal priority threads in process2 and 1 high priority thread in process2. If OS sets process1 to be of highest priority at the moment, there is no use for me to set thread priority in process2 ?

Comment: check this article as an example of how Windows manages it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a look in an hour. Just a quick question, same principles apply to linux?

Answer (score 0):

Both zr. and mark answers helped me.
I also found a way to set affinity for individual thread.
Check this link to see how: [pthread_attr_setaffinity_np()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_attr_setaffinity_np.3.html)

Thanks everyone who helped.